# Spring XsltViewResolver prefix path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, xslt

I want to use XSLT as my view technology in SpringBoot aplication.
I'm creating bean with `XsltViewResolver` but I'm not sure how to set prefix for this `ViewResolver`. I see examples online where xsl files are put in `WEB-INF/xsl` as below:

```
  @Bean
  public ViewResolver xsltViewResolver() {
      XsltViewResolver viewResolver = new XsltViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/xsl/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".xslt");
      return viewResolver;
  }
```

But as I have JAR packaging and no WEB-INF folder I put them in `src/main/resources/templates` and my prefix looks like this:

```
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
```

It doesn't work and when my controller is called I have `FileNotFound` exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/employees.xsl]
```

How can I set correct prefix?

Comment: Set your prefix from classpath:/templates

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view resolver bean should be

```
 @Bean
      public ViewResolver xsltViewResolver() {
          XsltViewResolver viewResolver = new XsltViewResolver();
          viewResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
          viewResolver.setSuffix(".xslt");
          return viewResolver;
      }
```